# How to create a project on BIM 360 Field using REST API?

Tags: c#, rest, cad, autodesk-forge

I am working on a Visual studio console application, which could download or write to the BIM 360 Field Website using REST services.

Currently, I am unable to create a sample project on the BIM 360 website. Kindly, help me in writing a C# function to create a sample project on BIM 360 Field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BIM 360 admin API to create a project:

https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-POST/

with "field" as a service_type parameter.

Comment: Thank you. I have gone through it but not able to understand. Is there a sample c# code for creating a project on BIM 360 ?

Comment: There is no C# sample at the moment unfortunately. This is a REST endpoint, you may need to laern how to perform http requests and work with a REST API if you are not used to. Take a look at RestSharp, a pretty good .Net API: http://restsharp.org. There you can find several samples and adapt it to any other REST API. Hope that helps.